# Viewing Radare keybindings for Visual Pane mode (Function hotkeys)?

Tags: radare2

Is there a way to view the keybinidngs inside of Radare? Such that I can see which function keys do things like Step Over and Step Into in Debug mode?

`e~key` doesn't list any of the debug keys,

```
key.S = 
key.f1 = 
key.f10 = 
key.f11 = 
key.f12 = 
key.f2 = 
key.f3 = 
key.f4 = 
key.f5 = 
key.f6 = 
key.f7 = 
key.f8 = 
key.f9 = 
key.s =
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are probably used if you remap the default ones. 
And those are visible when you press `?` in `V`isual mode, but not in Visual Pane mode (`V!`). Scrolling down will show the keys for debugging:

```
Function Keys: (See 'e key.'), defaults to:
  F2      toggle breakpoint
  F4      run to cursor
  F7      single step
  F8      step over
  F9      continue
```